# Is there a method for automating emails with SMTP or otherwise?

Tags: python, linux, email, automation, smtp

I've been writing some python scripts in order to do some automation for my work. One of the scripts is intended to gather some test results, compile the string of results with a "message" string, and send it as an email every 12-24 hours (if there are results) to each individual who needs this information. Additionally, we're running this script on Linux; either in a Jenkins pipeline, or in a crontab (this script will most likely be run via crontab).

I was initially using gmail's SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com, port 587) to send these since we're working off of our own personal gmail server anyways, and it worked for a bit once I gave the script an "App Password" since it was a "less secure app" to Google. However, after about an hour of testing with it, Google disabled the account for spam. Any subsequent accounts I try to set up for the same purpose are disabled on the spot, as well (the moment I try to send an email with it, it's halted and disabled). It's been a few days since I requested reviews on both of the accounts; but I don't think they'll get back to me any time soon, nor will it be a result in my favor.

Since Google was no longer viable, I looked online and saw that there are plenty of SMTP hosting options available, but we're not looking for a paid service just to send an email once every few days or so. In terms of free options, I was able to find one other post related to PHP/Ruby sending emails without SMTP ([Send email without external SMTP service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337451/send-email-without-external-smtp-service)), but if possible I'd like to keep this within Linux/Python only unless there is a simpler way, or a way that links well with Linux/Python. Even then, I'm still concerned that using SMTP is necessary for our gmail accounts to receive these emails. If I'm wrong, please correct me; because it certainly seems that way to me.

Based off of the situation, how could I adjust my strategy in order to automate email updates of this nature?

Comment: You can do it the oldschool way using a local MTA like postfix if you don't want to pay for a hosted service, but setting up, securing, and managing a MTA is notoriously a PITA.

Comment: Is Postfix relatively resource-lax?

Comment: Yes, most MTAs are.

Comment: They still come pre-installed on most linux distros so cron can deliver local mail, it's just not configured for external sending by default. Edit: something else you may find is that it's common for home ISPs to block outgoing port 25.

Comment: Indeed; from what I looked at on their site, it is available with most Linux kernels, or is at least installable (my case is installable; no immediately active postfix info from a "postfix ?" command). Once I get the okay from higher up, I'll see what I can do with Postfix and update this question accordingly.